# add table cells to class that inhiret UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have the following header file

```
@interface Menu : UITableViewController;
```

and the following m file

```
#import "Menu.h"

@implementation Menu

+ (void)initialize {

//  TODO here I want to add cells to my table view

 }



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{    

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES];

 //my logic goes here

 }

@end
```

I want to be able to add cells to my tableview in initialize method, how can I do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add cells to you table, you must implement the delegate and data source methods.

`- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` Will create and return a cell for the specified index path, which itself is basically a section and row number.

`- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`  Specifies the number of cells to be in the table.

You can see the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/).

There is a good tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial).